# Can't Delete row from gridview using command name

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

For many days I have been trying to delete row in gridview through command name, but I haven't been able to do this.

In the gridview row command I have added something as shown in code, to delete gridview row, so how can I delete that row?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionstring1");
    string str;
    str = "select * from Products INNER JOIN orders on Products.picID=orders.productID";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    con.Open();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("picID", typeof(int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("title", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("price", typeof(int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("dateAdded", typeof(DateTime)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("picURL", typeof(string)));
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["picID"] = Convert.ToInt32(reader["picID"]);
        dr["title"] = reader["title"];
        dr["price"] = Convert.ToInt32(reader["price"]);
        dr["dateAdded"] = reader["dateAdded"];
        dr["picURL"] = ResolveUrl("~/images/" + reader["picURL"]);
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }

}

protected void Gridview1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{


    if (e.CommandName == "removeRow")
    {
        string pic = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);
        deleteCart(pic);       
    }

}


private void deleteCart(string orderID)

{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionstring1");
    string str;
   str = "delete from orders where orderID='" + orderID + "'";

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    con.Close();

}
```

source

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"  OnRowCommand="Gridview1_RowCommand" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="picID" HeaderText="pic id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="price" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="dateAdded" HeaderText="date" />
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="picURL" HeaderText="image">
            </asp:ImageField>
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="remove" CommandName="removeRow" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a last added row from order table must be deleted"? Do you get an error message from DB or from client? What is the error message? What is the DDL for involved tables???

Comment: sorry not last added row,when i click on button in gridview row that row must be delete.
i have two table order and products,now gridview shows products with order,as i have written query in page_load,so to delete row that order data should be delete,what should i write in gridview1_rowcommand ??

i am just getting error incorrect syntax near "=" in cmd.executereader line,but dont know whether this code is right or not

Comment: `If(!ispotback){}` // your code needs to be in this while binding grid. If your Id is integer type in database it is a bad way to compare like this `delete from orders where orderID='" + orderID + "'";` instead you can do this like `delete from orders where orderID=" + orderID;`

Comment: You can use `ExecuteNonQuery` after your command statement

Comment: refer this same you have to do for delete here done for  inserting http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-addupdate-record-using-gridview.html

Comment: tried,error is gone but cant delete row,is the process right which i have written?

Comment: @vikas: after delete qquery fire check your database, whethre record is deleted and then in code you need to rebind your gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your code in imporved version**

For `Add/ Update/ Delete` you should use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead of `cmd.ExecuteReader();`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
     girdivewBind();
  }
}

  protected void Gridview1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.CommandName == "removeRow")
     {
        string pic = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);
        deleteCart(pic);   
        girdivewBind(); // Bind your gridview again.    
      }
  }


public void deleteCart(string orderID)
{
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cn.ConnectionString))
   {
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
     {
        cmd.CommandText = "delete from orders where orderID=@id";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", orderID);
        con.Open();
        var temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
       }
   }
 }

 public void girdivewBind()
 { 
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionstring1");
   string str = "select * from Products INNER JOIN orders on Products.picID=orders.productID";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
   con.Open();
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("picID", typeof(int)));
   dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("title", typeof(string)));
   dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("price", typeof(int)));
   dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("dateAdded", typeof(DateTime)));
   dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("picURL", typeof(string)));
   SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   while (reader.Read())
     {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["picID"] = Convert.ToInt32(reader["picID"]);
        dr["title"] = reader["title"];
        dr["price"] = Convert.ToInt32(reader["price"]);
        dr["dateAdded"] = reader["dateAdded"];
        dr["picURL"] = ResolveUrl("~/images/" + reader["picURL"]);
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
       } reader.Close();
         con.Close();
       GridView1.DataSource = dt;
       GridView1.DataBind();
     }
  }
```

Comment: @vikas: delect record from gridview and check from sql server whether record is delete from database ??

Comment: debugging shows that it is not moving in deletecart method,it just stops at deleteCart(pic);   
         girdivewBind();

Comment: @vikas: what value you getting in variable   `string pic` also post you html markup

Comment: getting id of product which is picID ,on row which i have clicked

Comment: @vikas: I already answer   ,did you tired mine ,your deleteCart method is wrong replace with my answer , also make is `public` not `private` and your gridview binding should be outside the while(reader.read){} as i mention in my answer. i cant help you more if you not show some effort from yourself